# Special Characters in non english languages

Tags: internationalization, locale

How can I generate a text file containing all character codes in a specific locale for example 1029 Czech. I basically want to generate a list of every character that exists in their alphabet?

Comment: What language/environment are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Windows locale, just generate a file with all bytes from 32 to 255: The byte codes for the locales are the same; they just interpret each byte differently. See [this page](http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-Codes.asp?s=codepage) for links.

Example: The byte 0xa5 stands for "Ą" in the Czech codepage (1250) while it's "¥" in the German codepage (1252 a.k.a ISO-Latin-1).

[EDIT] Note that this only works for pre-Unicode locales where one byte maps to exactly one character. It doesn't work for any Asian locale which need two or more bytes per character.

Comment: This will probably not work as you expect in quite a few languages, most notably chinese, japanese, thai, korean etc.

Comment: Correct, it won't work on Asian languages but he was wondering about something that isn't Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a script in python + beautiful soup that grabs all of them from:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 0):

CLDR (Common Locale Data Repository, http://cldr.unicode.org/) contains that information.

But there is really no good reason to care, if you handle everything with Unicode.
The European Union has now member countries that use characters across several of the "traditional" code pages: Western European, Eastern European, Turkish, Baltic, Greek, Cyrillic. Unicode is the only way.